# Linq to XML treating results individually instead of listing

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm working on a parser in C# to take data from multiple xml files and put them into my own database.

Right now I have this code that works:

```
 List<CaseFile> caseFiles =
            (
                from e in XDocument.Load(xmlDoc).Root.Elements("application-information").Elements("file-segments").Elements("action-keys").Elements("case-file")
                select new CaseFile
                { (......)
}).toList();
```

This creates a list of CaseFile objects which I later send to other methods to place their data into my database. The problem with this is that I need to parse many files at once, some as big as 1GB and none smaller than 200MB so this creates a massive demand for memory.

Is there a way to modify my statement so for every CaseFile it finds, it sends it instantly to the other methods instead of having to create the full list of them first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`XDocument.Load` will load whole file into the memory first. For quick searching elements return `IEnumerable` of CaseFire objects and use `XmlReader` to read file node by node (assume you have `case-file` nodes only at `root/application-information/file-segments/action-keys` otherwise you will need more logic here):

```
static IEnumerable<CaseFile> FindCaseFiles(string uri)
{
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(uri))
    {
        reader.MoveToContent();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    if (reader.Name == "case-file")
                    {
                        XElement el = XElement.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;
                        if (el != null)
                            yield return new CaseFile() {...};
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
foreach(CaseFile file in FindCaseFiles(path_to_xml))
{
    // we have CaseFile here immediately after it found in xml file
}
```

Comment: The solution looks like what I want but I'm running into trouble implementing it. To make it work I had to make the CaseFile class implement IEnumerable but now I have to make it implement IEnumerator's methods and I'm not sure that is even logically correct (it seems to be making CaseFiles into a list of objects where it's just an object I want to make a list of)... It's telling me it doesn't contain a definition for "Add" now (error points to the "from ..." line of the linq query) and I don't even know how exactly to implement that...

Comment: @ConnorU sorry, didn't get - why should CaseFile implement IEnumerable?

Comment: The compiler told me so... I put the code you suggested in and it wouldn't run because it said CaseFile didn't implement it... "Error 3 Cannot initialize type 'TrademarkParserproject.CaseFile' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' "

Comment: @ConnorU just created sample xml and verified - all works fine. Are you trying to return CaseFile? You should use `yield return`

Comment: I just realized where the problem was, I left my query in and it had "Select new casefile" in it which gave the error. Thanks, this should work. Gives me a "control cannot fall from one case label to another" error but I should be able to figure that one out on my own. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just drop the ToList and declare your variable as an IEnumerable (or just use var) should do the trick. 
Using linq to XML may not be indicated for big files though as it loads all the file in memory. You should consider using à XmlReader instead

Comment: What do you mean drop it?What do I put in it's stead to make it create a single casefile, once, for evry casefile in the database?

Also, what alternative to linq-to-xml would you suggest?

Comment: Nothing ! Linq select creates an enumerable with the wanted 'streaming' behaviour

Comment: Consider using à XmlReader for example. À little bit harder to use, but more memory friendly

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you call ToList on the result of your LINQ-Expression. This will enumerate over all the values and write everything to memory. The LINQ-Expression itself does not enumerate over the values. It will just return an IEnumerable. No CaseFile-objects will be created by the LINQ-Expression.

If you just loop through the result of the LINQ-Expression it will read one value after the other:

```
var caseFiles = from e in XDocument.Load(xmlDoc).Root.
                    Elements("application-information").
                    Elements("file-segments").
                    Elements("action-keys").
                    Elements("case-file")
                select new CaseFile { ... };

foreach (CaseFile cf in caseFiles)
{
    DoTheWork(cf);
}
```

This way only one CaseFile-object will be created at any time.